# How to use if condition more efficiently?

Tags: kotlin, if-statement

I have a little knowledge in programming but I have a doubt about the following if statement.

```
val age = 21
if(age >= 21) {
    println("You can drink now")
} else if(age >= 18) {
    println("You can vote now")
} else if(age >= 16) {
   println("You can drive now")
} else{
   println("You are too young")
}
```

In the above if statement, all conditions are true but I know only the first condition will be executed. If I want to check all the conditions are true, I could use seperate if conditions for all criteria. Is there any way to make this possible in a more efficient way. Please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [kotlin currently doesn't support](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/fall-through-in-when/2540/2) the java `switch` statement functionality where one can go all through the cases (unless `break` is used)

I think this looks quite good in kotlin:

```
    if (age >= 21) println("You can drink now")
    if (age >= 18) println("You can vote now")
    if (age >= 16) println("You can drive now")
    if (age < 16) println("You are too young")
```

Comment: A nice simple solution to a simple problem. No need for complexity here.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't have `switch` because it does not need it. It has `when`.

Comment: @Alex.T java's `switch` and kotlin's `when` behave differently. `switch` will execute all expressions that are true while `when` will stop once the first expression is true. The OP wants to execute all statements that are true

Answer (score 0):

In functional way:

```
val age = 21

listOf<Pair<(Int) -> Boolean, () -> Unit>>(
        { i:Int -> i >= 21 } to { println("You can drink now") },
        { i:Int -> i >= 18 } to { println("You can vote now") },
        { i:Int -> i >= 16 } to { println("You can drive now") },
        { i:Int -> i <  16 } to { println("You are too young") }
).forEach { (check, action) ->
    if (check.invoke(age)) {
        action.invoke()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If some condition is true only if another one is true, then you may nest them to avoid  redundant checks in case when more general condition is false:

```kotlin
if (age >= 16) {
    if (age >= 18) { // Will not be executed if age < 16
        if (age >= 21) { // Will not be executed if age < 18
            println("You can drink now")
        }
        println("You can vote now")
    }
    println("You can drive now")
} else {
    println("You are too young")
}
```

It's a bit more effitient, but far less readable than simple:

```kotlin
if (age >= 21) println("You can drink now")
if (age >= 18) println("You can vote now")
if (age >= 16) println("You can drive now")
if (age < 16) println("You are too young")
```

So, if conditions checks are cheap and/or performance is not an absolute priority in your case, I'd choose the latter variant.